# jquery, Autocomplete URL call using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery to implement autocomplete to my textbox, i have used Ajax call,but my ajax url is not working.

When i inspect it is showing this error -> POST http://localhost:51444/Searchoperation/searchvalues 404 (Not Found)

> My HTML and Script code

```js
    <script>
        $('#myInput').keyup(function (event)
        { 
            var searchname = $('#myInput').val()
            $('#myInput').autocomplete(
            {  
                scroll: true,  
                selectFirst: false,  
                autoFocus: false,  
                source: function(request, response)  
                {  
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         url: "Searchoperation/searchvalues",
                         data: "{'Searchname':'" + searchname + "'}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('/')[0],
                                    val: item.split('/')[1]
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (result) { }
                     });
                },
          
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var vll = ui.item.val;
                    var sts = "no";
                    var url = 'search_app.aspx?prefix=' + searchname; // ur own conditions  
                    $(location).attr('href', url);
                }
           })
      })
    </script>
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="search-field" style="width:300px;">-->
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="SearchName" >
</div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> Code for fetching values from database

```
public List<string> searchvalues(string searchname)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            string connectionstring = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-LTV06QJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Search;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "connection_string";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_Search", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_Name", searchname);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(string.Format("{0}/{1}", dr["Emp_id"], dr["Emp_Name"]));
            }
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

**value entered in textbox is read but ajax call is not working.please help**

Comment: I hope you have declared [WebMethod] becfore searchvalues method. Are you using asp.net c#?

Comment: Added WebMethod.still not working,still same error @JitendraRangpariya

Comment: Are you using asp.net c#?

Comment: yes @JitendraRangpariya

Answer (score 0):

try to use slash in the beginning of the path ("/Searchoperation/searchvalues"):

```
$.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         url: "/Searchoperation/searchvalues",
                         data: "{'Searchname':'" + searchname + "'}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('/')[0],
                                    val: item.split('/')[1]
                                }
                            }));
                        },

....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing page extension(.ASPX). Replace the ajax attribute URL like below,

`url: "Searchoperation.aspx/searchvalues"`

Also, make sure you have added [WebMethod] before the searchvalues method.

I hope this will help.

Comment: that page extension is .cs @Jitendra Rangpariya

Comment: As you said, you are using asp.net c# so i hope frant end page is ASPX where you have written `<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="SearchName" >`

Comment: its in aspx @Jitendra Rangpariya

Comment: Please follow my answer practically and let me know if does not work.

Comment: I want to call cs page not aspx page. that's why this error occurs.@Jitendra Rangpariya

Comment: @joe17 If you want to call CS WebMethod by AJAX post as you doing in question code, you must need to follow URL as I mentioned in this post. Please try and let me know if you are getting any error with description.

Comment: @joe17 Loot at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184902/ajax-post-with-asp-net-webforms) AJAX code(URL attribute) for reference.